# How to see addresses in Graph view in IDA

Tags: ida, ollydbg

In IDA, when I want to see the address of code, I must switch to Text view.

How can I see the address of code in Graph view?

By the way, is there Graph view in OllyDbg?

Comment: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/14671/18563

Answer (score 9):

Switch to graph mode, then go to menu Options-General, Disassembly tab and enable

- `[x] Line Prefixes (graph)`

Other disassembly options : https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/605.shtml.

You can also check the status bar, it displays the current address.