# Error when changing push 0 to push function

Tags: ida, assembly

Hi I am sort of new to ida pro even though I've used a lot but when I push a function where a 0 used to be it gives me sp-analysis failure
[image]

I've searched for a fix for a while to no avail
help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on bytes. You'll see you don't have enough space. You're going to have to figure out where to steal some. Wherever that is, via jump short, you need a couple more bytes.

Comment: How do I turn on bytes?

Comment: Try this question: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14422/how-do-i-know-the-bytes-corresponding-to-an-instruction-in-hex-view-in-ida

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are changing `2` bytes instruction `push 0` into `push offset` which is 5 bytes instruction. So you overwrite subsequent instruction’s prefix and that’s why sp analysis fails (`push offset Studio_done` changed to `db 0` and `pop`, so you have `pop` instead of `push`).